# Snake Game in Java - Snake leaving Spaces

Tags: java

I'm making a snake game and well It's done I can just export it and everything. Just one simple problem; For whatever reason the snake leaves spaces everytime the bodyParts increases. I didn't calculate by how much exactly but everytime the bodyParts increases, the tail leaves spaces more.
I've tried to look for the problem.

*This is my first Game Project ever so please don't judge me xd.*

These are the code.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_HEIGHT*SCREEN_WIDTH)/UNIT_SIZE;
    static final int DELAY = 175;
    final int x[] = new int [GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int [GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 1;
    int applesEaten;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    private Image tail;
    private Image apple;
    private Image head;

    GamePanel() {
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_HEIGHT,SCREEN_WIDTH));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
        loadImages();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        running = true;
        newApple();
        Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon("src/res/tail.png");
        tail = iid.getImage();
        ImageIcon iia = new ImageIcon("src/res/apple.png");
        apple = iia.getImage();
        ImageIcon iih = new ImageIcon("src/res/head.png");
        head = iih.getImage();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
            //g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0 , i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
           // g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE); //grids
        }
        g.drawImage(apple, appleX, appleY, this);  //apple
        for (int z = 0; z < bodyParts; z++) {
            if (z == 0) {
                g.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z], this);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(tail, x[z], y[z], this);
            }
        }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    public void newApple() {
        appleX = random.nextInt((SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE))*UNIT_SIZE;
        appleY = random.nextInt((SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE))*UNIT_SIZE;
    }

    public void move() {
        for(int z = bodyParts;z>0;z--) {
            x[z] = x[(z-1)];
            y[z] = y[(z-1)];
            switch(direction) {
            case 'U':
                y[0] -= UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'D':
                y[0] += UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'L':
                x[0] -= UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'R':
                x[0] += UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkApple() {
        if((x[0] == appleX) && (y[0] == appleY)) {
            bodyParts++;
            applesEaten++;
            newApple();
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {
        //checks if head collides with body
        for(int i = bodyParts;i<0;i--) {
            if((x[0] == x[i])&& (y[0] == y[i])) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        //checks if head touches left border
        if(x[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }

        //check if head touches right border
        if(x[0] > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            running = false;
        }

        //check if head touches top border
        if(y[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }

        //check if head touches bottom border
        if(y[0] > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            running = false;
        }
        if(!running) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(running) {
            move();
            checkApple();
            checkCollisions();
            loadImages();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if(direction != 'R') {
                    direction = 'L';
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if(direction != 'L') {
                    direction = 'R';
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                if(direction != 'D') {
                    direction = 'U';
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                if(direction != 'U') {
                    direction = 'D';
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is when the bodyParts = 2 [bodyParts = 2;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcE36.png)

And, this is when the bodyParts = 3
[bodyParts = 3;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRUlD.png)

Comment: I can't imagine your code working at all as it contains so many bugs! For example, the termination condition in the loop `for (int i = bodyParts; i < 0; i--)` is false, it should probably be `i>=0`. In the `startTimer` function, the line `Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);` is wrong because it creates a new local timer object, which hides the class timer! These two errors alone prevent the program from working at all!

Comment: Take a look at this Snake [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365).