# My snake doesn't get the score from the right location

Tags: java, graphics, awt, game-development

```
    public void checkScore() {
            if(xAxis[0] == appleX && yAxis[0] == appleY) {
                newApple();
                score++;
                bodyParts++;
            }
    }
```

I'm making my very own snake game with java and I have this problem where my snake doesn't secure the score even when it's touching it but somehow it takes the score from somewhere else when there is nothing for it to collide I tried debugging my code and realized that the positions are correct the condition is correct but there is some sort of problem with the visuals(what I mean by that is the snake and score point are not exactly located in their coordinates) even though my draw function is completely right
draw function:

```
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
            if(isRunning) {
                for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i * UNIT_SIZE, 0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
                    g.drawLine(0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i * UNIT_SIZE);
                } 
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g.fillOval(appleX, appleX, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                for(int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
                    if(i == 0) {
                        g.setColor(new Color(138,43,226).darker());
                        g.fillRect(xAxis[i], yAxis[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(new Color(138,43,226));
                        g.fillRect(xAxis[i], yAxis[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                   }
                }
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 25));
                FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
                g.drawString("Score = " + score, (SCREEN_WIDTH - 
    metrics.stringWidth("Score = "  + score)) / 2, g.getFont().getSize()); 
            } else {
                gameOver(g);
           }
    
        }
```

Comment: Here's a [lengthy explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365) about another snake game.

Comment: Thank you so much but I found it myself as I thought this was a problem of visuals I noticed that I mistyped appleX in the fillOval function as y parameter so that's why but thank you for the help <3