# How do I restart Snake game (Java)?

Tags: java, game-development

I'm a beginner so I used Bro Code's (a YouTuber) version of snake game. It's almost identical with minor adjustments, but I've been trying to figure out how to restart the game when I die. I've tried making a  restart button and tried to make it restart with a keystroke but I've got no experience coding so I couldn't figure it out. Here's the source code:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel<Restart> extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1300;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 750;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / (UNIT_SIZE * UNIT_SIZE);
    static final int DELAY = 85;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 5;
    int applesEaten;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;

    GamePanel() {
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        newApple();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (running) {
            /*
             * for(int i=0;i<SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE;i++) { g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0,
             * i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT); g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH,
             * i*UNIT_SIZE); }
             */
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
            for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }
                else {
                    g.setColor(new Color(45, 180, 0));
                    // g.setColor(new
                    // Color(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }
            }
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 40));
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Score: " + applesEaten,
                    (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth("Score: " + applesEaten)) / 2,
                    g.getFont().getSize());
        }
        else {
            gameOver(g);
        }
    }

    public void newApple() {
        appleX = random.nextInt((int) (SCREEN_WIDTH / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
        appleY = random.nextInt((int) (SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
    }

    public void move() {
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }
        switch (direction) {
            case 'U':
                y[0] = y[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'D':
                y[0] = y[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'L':
                x[0] = x[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'R':
                x[0] = x[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void checkApple() {
        if ((x[0] == appleX) && (y[0] == appleY)) {
            bodyParts++;
            applesEaten++;
            newApple();
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {
        // checks if head collides with body
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            if ((x[0] == x[i]) && (y[0] == y[i])) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        // check if head touches left border
        if (x[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        // check if head touches right border
        if (x[0] > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            running = false;
        }
        // check if head touches top border
        if (y[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        // check if head touches bottom border
        if (y[0] > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (!running) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        // Score
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 40));
        FontMetrics metrics1 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Score: " + applesEaten,
                (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics1.stringWidth("Score: " + applesEaten)) / 2,
                g.getFont().getSize());
        // Game Over text
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 75));
        FontMetrics metrics2 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Game Over", (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics2.stringWidth("Game Over")) / 2,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (running) {
            move();
            checkApple();
            checkCollisions();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                    if (direction != 'R') {
                        direction = 'L';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                    if (direction != 'L') {
                        direction = 'R';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                    if (direction != 'D') {
                        direction = 'U';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                    if (direction != 'U') {
                        direction = 'D';
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I'm a beginner so I [copied and pasted] [someone else's] [code]... but I've got no experience coding so I couldn't figure it out" This is a fundamentally misguided approach. Please try to find a tutorial for the Java language, and begin at the beginning. It is only possible to learn things that you understand. As it stands, you are now left without the skills necessary to *ask the question properly*.

Comment: Here's a [Snake game StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365) that better explains what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, Pressing Enter will close the previous window and open a new game window. Let me know if you don't understand something so I can explain it to you!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public final class GamePanel<Restart> extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1300;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 750;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / (UNIT_SIZE * UNIT_SIZE);
    static final int DELAY = 85;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 5;
    int applesEaten;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;

    public void createGUI() {
        panel.add(new GamePanel());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    GamePanel() {
        random = new Random();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        newApple();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (running) {
            /*
             * for(int i=0;i<SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE;i++) { g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0,
             * i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT); g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH,
             * i*UNIT_SIZE); }
             */
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
            for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(new Color(45, 180, 0));
                    // g.setColor(new
                    // Color(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }
            }
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 40));
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Score: " + applesEaten,
                    (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth("Score: " + applesEaten)) / 2,
                    g.getFont().getSize());
        } else {
            gameOver(g);
        }
    }

    public void newApple() {
        appleX = random.nextInt((int) (SCREEN_WIDTH / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
        appleY = random.nextInt((int) (SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
    }

    public void move() {
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }
        switch (direction) {
            case 'U':
                y[0] = y[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'D':
                y[0] = y[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'L':
                x[0] = x[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
            case 'R':
                x[0] = x[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void checkApple() {
        if ((x[0] == appleX) && (y[0] == appleY)) {
            bodyParts++;
            applesEaten++;
            newApple();
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {
        // checks if head collides with body
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            if ((x[0] == x[i]) && (y[0] == y[i])) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        // check if head touches left border
        if (x[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        // check if head touches right border
        if (x[0] > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            running = false;
        }
        // check if head touches top border
        if (y[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        // check if head touches bottom border
        if (y[0] > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (!running) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        // Score
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 40));
        FontMetrics metrics1 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Score: " + applesEaten,
                (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics1.stringWidth("Score: " + applesEaten)) / 2,
                g.getFont().getSize());
        // Game Over text
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 75));
        FontMetrics metrics2 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Game Over", (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics2.stringWidth("Game Over")) / 2,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (running) {
            move();
            checkApple();
            checkCollisions();
        }
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void closeRunningWindow(KeyEvent e) {
        JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
        win.dispose();
    }
    
    public void startAgain() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
            game.createGUI();
        });
    }

    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                    if (direction != 'R') {
                        direction = 'L';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                    if (direction != 'L') {
                        direction = 'R';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                    if (direction != 'D') {
                        direction = 'U';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                    if (direction != 'U') {
                        direction = 'D';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                    closeRunningWindow(e);
                    startAgain();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
            game.createGUI();
        });
    }
}
```