# How to fill JPanel with Interact-able squares with a grid layout?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, awt

I am trying to make a version of Snake Game in Java that uses a JFrame + JPanel combination in which the JPanel contains an all black background and draws a grid of squares with a white outline (drawRect) and fill it with the color dark gray (fillRect) that are each 5 x 5 in width and height. However when adding each Node/Square to the panels gridLayout, running the program simply does not display the window at all. Only after commenting out the initNodes function does it display a window with a black background. How would I be able to make interact-able squares within a JPanel grid layout?

Board.java

```
package snakegame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board {

    JFrame window;

    JPanel panel;

    Graphics g;

    protected final Node[][] nodes = new Node[800][1000];

    protected static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
    protected static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;

    public Board(){
        initBoard();
    }

    private void initPanel(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(800,1000));
        initNodes();
        window.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    private void initNodes(){
        for(int row = 0; row < nodes.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < nodes[row].length; col++){
                nodes[row][col] = new Node(row, col); //Whenever this is called this should draw a square at each node
                panel.add(nodes[row][col]); //Add to panel grid layout
            }
        }
    }

    private void initBoard(){

        window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("JSnake!");
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initPanel();

        window.pack();

        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Node.java

```
package snakegame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Node extends JPanel {

    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    public Node(int x, int  y){
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawRect(this.xPos,this.yPos, Board.WINDOW_WIDTH/200,Board.WINDOW_HEIGHT/ 160);
        g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2.fillRect(this.xPos,this.yPos,Board.WINDOW_WIDTH/200,Board.WINDOW_HEIGHT/ 160);
    }

}
```

Comment: Node needs to override `public Dimension getPreferredSize() {...}` where it returns a decent preferred size. Else it will return the default preferred size of [0, 0]

Comment: Also, you're drawing to the wrong location. The location should  be relative to the individual Node JPanel itself.

Comment: Don't use all your hard coded numbers such as the window width/height. That value doesn't make sense because the size of the window includes the frame decorations (title bar and borders). Instead you set the preferred size of each node as suggested above and you set the row/columns of the grid. Then after adding all the nodes to the panel and the panel to the frame you pack the frame and the frame size will be calculated properly based on the preferred size of all the child components added to the frame. Then when painting the node you should use getWidth() and getHeight().

Comment: Also, is 1000 columns reasonable? My screen size is only 1024. You want your nodes to take up 5,000 pixels. I don't know of many monitors that large. maybe your game should query the screen size to determine the maximum number of columns/row that can be displayed based on your preferred node size.

Comment: You might get some ideas from this Snake [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting greatly, I decided to scrap that project and make a completely new version that in my opinion is much more organized and has 4 files in total, I would like to add that the game itself is not finished as that is not what my question was asking, rather it was asking how to make a proper grid layout for using JPanel + JFrame (hence why you will see so many import statements that will be removed) and here is my solution:

Main.java:

```
package snakegame;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            var gameFrame = new GameFrame();
            gameFrame.window.setVisible(true);

        });

    }

}
```

GameFrame.java:

```
package snakegame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameFrame {

    JFrame window;
    Game panel;

    public GameFrame(){
        window = new JFrame();
        panel = new Game();
        window.setUndecorated(false);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setTitle("JSnake");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.add(panel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Node.java:

```
package snakegame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Node extends JPanel {

    private final int SIZE = 20;

    public Node(){
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE,SIZE));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}
```

Game.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final int DELAY = 75;

    private Node[][] grid = new Node[40][40];

    private char direction;

    Timer timer;

    public Game(){

        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        startGame();

    }

    private void startGame(){
        initNodes();
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    private JPanel initNodes(){

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(40,40,0,0));

        for(int row = 0; row <= grid.length - 1; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col <= grid[row].length - 1; col++){
                grid[row][col] = new Node();
                this.add(grid[row][col]);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    //Create the game loop
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    //Check for key presses to use in the moveSnake method
    public class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    if (direction != 'R') {
                        direction = 'L';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    if (direction != 'L') {
                        direction = 'R';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    if (direction != 'D') {
                        direction = 'U';
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    if (direction != 'U') {
                        direction = 'D';
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```