# Graphics are not showing up in java swing window

Tags: java, swing

When I try and draw a grid in the window or draw a random at a random location, neither show up. The only thing I seem to be able to change is the background color.

Here is the code for the program:

SnakeGame:

```java
public class SnakeGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

GameFrame:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    GameFrame() {
        this.add(new GamePanel());
        this.setTitle("Snake");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

GamePanel:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / UNIT_SIZE;
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 6;
    int applesEaten;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    
    GamePanel() {
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }
    
    public void startGame() {
        newApple();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i * UNIT_SIZE, 0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            g.drawLine(0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i * UNIT_SIZE);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
    }
    
    public void newApple() {
        appleX = random.nextInt((int)(SCREEN_WIDTH / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
        appleX = random.nextInt((int)(SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
    }
    
    public void move() {
        
    }
    
    public void checkApple() {
        
    }
    
    public void checkCollisions() {
        
    }
    
    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    
    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using the `drawLine()`, `setColor()`, and `fillOval()` methods to draw a grid and make an "apple" but, when I do, nothing is shown in the window and all I see is the empty window with whichever background color I chose.

```
type here
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: You never call draw (from paintComponent) and repaint from actionPerformed

Comment: Perhaps this explanation from another [question about a Java Snake game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365) will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments.  Some action is performed which here is to call `repaint()`.  That then causes `paintComponent` to be called which will draw the grid.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g); //<-- added
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      repaint(); // <--  added
        
}
```