# can anyone please tell why the message is not displaying in end when we are out?

Tags: java, computer-science, game-development

When I am out there a message should be displayed which is not being displayed please check it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SnakeGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    // game variables
    private int score;
    private boolean gameOver;
    private Timer timer;

    // board variables
    private static final int ROWS = 20;
    private static final int COLS = 20;
    private static final int CELL_SIZE = 30;
    private int[][] board;

    // snake variables
    private int snakeLength;
    private int[] snakeX;
    private int[] snakeY;
    private int dx;
    private int dy;

    public SnakeGame() {
        // initialize variables
        score = 0;
        gameOver = false;
        board = new int[ROWS][COLS];
        snakeLength = 3;
        snakeX = new int[ROWS*COLS];
        snakeY = new int[ROWS*COLS];
        dx = CELL_SIZE;
        dy = 0;

        // create the game board
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(COLS*CELL_SIZE, ROWS*CELL_SIZE));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new SnakeKeyListener());

        // start the game timer
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        timer.start();

        // generate initial snake and food
        generateSnake();
        generateFood();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        // update the snake position
        int headX = snakeX[0] + dx;
        int headY = snakeY[0] + dy;

        // check for collision with walls or body
        if (headX < 0 || headX >= COLS*CELL_SIZE || headY < 0 || headY >= ROWS*CELL_SIZE || board[headY/CELL_SIZE][headX/CELL_SIZE] > 0) {
            gameOver = true;
            return;
        }
        if (gameOver) {
            return;
        }
        // check for food
        if (board[headY/CELL_SIZE][headX/CELL_SIZE] == -1) {
            snakeLength++;
            score++;
            generateFood();
        }

        // move the snake
        for (int i = snakeLength-1; i > 0; i--) {
            snakeX[i] = snakeX[i-1];
            snakeY[i] = snakeY[i-1];
        }
        snakeX[0] = headX;
        snakeY[0] = headY;

        // update the board
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] > 0) {
                    board[i][j]--;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; i++) {
            board[snakeY[i]/CELL_SIZE][snakeX[i]/CELL_SIZE] = snakeLength-i;
        }

        // repaint the board
        repaint();
    }

    private void generateSnake() {
        // generate initial snake position and direction
        int snakeStartX = (COLS/2) * CELL_SIZE;
        int snakeStartY = (ROWS/2) * CELL_SIZE;
        snakeX[0] = snakeStartX;
        snakeY[0] = snakeStartY;
        snakeX[1] = snakeStartX - CELL_SIZE;
        snakeY[1] = snakeStartY;
        snakeX[2] = snakeStartX - (2 * CELL_SIZE);
        snakeY[2] = snakeStartY;
    }

    private void generateFood() {
        // generate food at a random position on the board
        int foodX = (int) (Math.random() * COLS) * CELL_SIZE;
        int foodY = (int) (Math.random() * ROWS) * CELL_SIZE;

        // check that food is not generated on the snake
        if (board[foodY/CELL_SIZE][foodX/CELL_SIZE] != 0) {
            generateFood();
        } else {
            board[foodY/CELL_SIZE][foodX/CELL_SIZE] = -1;
        }
    }

    private class SnakeKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && dx == 0) {
                dx = -CELL_SIZE;
                dy = 0;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && dx == 0) {
                dx = CELL_SIZE;
                dy = 0;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && dy == 0) {
                dx = 0;
                dy = -CELL_SIZE;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && dy == 0) {
                dx = 0;
                dy = CELL_SIZE;
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // draw the board
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == -1) {
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g.fillRect(j*CELL_SIZE, i*CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
                } else if (board[i][j] > 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.fillRect(j*CELL_SIZE, i*CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
                }
            }
        }

        // draw the snake
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; i++) {
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(snakeX[i], snakeY[i], CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
        }

        // draw the score
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Score: " + score, 10, 20);

        // draw game over message
        if (gameOver) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Game Over!", COLS*CELL_SIZE/2 - 30, ROWS*CELL_SIZE/2);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over! Your score is " + score, "Snake Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SnakeGame(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried every possible solution I know.
The objective of the project is to develop a classic arcade-style game in which the player controls a "snake" that grows in length as it eats food while avoiding collision with the walls and its own body. The game should be developed using Java programming language and should be designed with a graphical user interface that includes a playable game area, game controls, and a scoring system. The game should also feature various levels of difficulty and should be able to save and load high scores. Additionally, the game should be able to handle user input and respond to events such as collisions and the snake's movement. The aim of the project is to develop an engaging and entertaining game that provides a fun and challenging experience to the player.

Comment: Please don't copy-paste your subject and precise what you're expecting exactly

Comment: Maybe this [Snake game explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365) might help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call JOptionPane.showMessageDialog in paintComponent. It should only be used to paint.

Add

```
if(gameOver) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over! Your score is " + score, "Snake Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
}
```

to the start of actionPerformed and delete the Dialog and exit part from paintComponent