# Adding objects onto JPanels

Tags: java, swing

I am doing my first project involving the JFrame and JPanel modules. I am trying to make a simple version of the iconic snake game. The current Panel structure im using is as follows:

I have a GamePanel that is supposed to hold the other panels. I added a background panel that includes the cells to the GamePanel. Now I am trying to draw food onto the GamePanel. I have been trying to just use the add method to add more panels on top of the background panel however, this doesnt seem to work. When trying to add a second panel to the GamePanel, only the background Panel shows up.

I want to draw the food object onto the GamePanel. How do I add new panels to the GamePanel? Is there a different way to add new objects to a Panel?

Here is some of the code that I have written:

```java
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private int cellSize;
    private int boardSizeX;
    private int boardSizeY;
    public GamePanel(int x, int y, int cellSize) {
        this.boardSizeX = x;
        this.boardSizeY = y;
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100 + x * cellSize, 100 + y * cellSize));
        this.add(new Board(x, y, cellSize));
    }
}
```

```java
public class Board extends JPanel {
    private int cellSize;
    private int boardSizeX;
    private int boardSizeY;
    public Board(int x, int y, int cellSize) {
        this.boardSizeX = x;
        this.boardSizeY = y;
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100 + x * cellSize, 100 + y * cellSize));
        this.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }


    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g) {


        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Background
        g2D.setPaint(new Color(41, 41, 41));
        g2D.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        g2D.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        int to = this.getHeight() - 50;
        int cord = 50;
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeX + 1; i++) {
            g2D.drawLine(cord, 50, cord, to);
            cord += cellSize;
        }
        to = this.getWidth() - 50;
        cord = 50;
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeY + 1; i++) {
            g2D.drawLine(50, cord, to, cord);
            cord += cellSize;
        }

    }
}
```

```java
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    public MyFrame(int x, int y, int cellSize) {

        gamePanel = new GamePanel(x, y, cellSize);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Snake Game");

        this.add(gamePanel);
        this.pack();


        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GamePanel getGamePanel() {
        return gamePanel;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Testing extends JComponent {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
        g2D.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 40;
        int y = 40;
        int cellSize = 15;
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(x, y, cellSize);
        Testing test = new Testing();
        frame.getGamePanel().add(test);
        frame.getGamePanel().repaint();
    }
}
```

The problem is that test JComponent isnt showing up in the frame.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Is there a different way to add new objects to a Panel?"  Yes.  You can draw them.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: Here's a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701646/snake-game-in-java-but-my-restart-button-does-not-work/70711365#70711365) that explains what you should consider when creating a Snake (or any other) game.